# How to open a link clicked in an external application in my, already openend application

Tags: browser, hyperlink, communication-protocol

**So we all know how smooth switching between browsers and apps can be from our androids and iPhones.
My question is:
Can we archieve anything similiar on windows machines?**

**Scenario:**
1. I get a link in a windows application like skype or outlook.
2. I press the link.
3. Magic: Somehow, somebody checks if my web application is already open in the clients browser.
4. The browser opens the already existing instance of my web application, recieves the parameters from the link and does his work.

**Possible Solution/Hack that I though of:**
1. When a link is openend in my application, notify the server and check if the user is already active in a different tab.
2. If yes, we show a info-page in the newly opened tab, that states that the link has been forwarded to the server and will be processed by the already existing instance of the web application.

**Is there a built in way in Windows?**

I've looked around for a while but haven't found anything useful that would be applicable for more than only one application (through plugins / browser extensions)

Thanks!

Comment: Opening an external program from a webpage exposes serious security hazards. This is not as much of a risk on mobile OSs where all installed applications have permissions and a certain level of trust.  On a desktop system, there is not as much control available.

Comment: That's a valid point. But I asked if there is a standardized concept that could do something like that trough a browser plugin or a desktop application. In that case the security issue can be controlled.